# Meteor log out do not sync between tabs

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, meteor-accounts

I am using Meteor with React and is facing a problem on log out function. When I open more than 2 tabs on the same browser, If I logged out from one tab then the other opening tabs would not be logged out but will be hang if I using it. There are only 2 ways to log out: close the tab or refresh it.

I try the same for log in function and it worked, log in status is synced between all opening tabs.

My current code to call the log out function:

```
signOut: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.logout();
    this.props.history.pushState(null, "/");
},
```

Thank for the helps.

**Update:**
I checked the websocket, it's seem that the server did send the logout status but my client code did not call the logout method (or it is hang). Then every data in the hang tab is still existing. But I don't know how to check further more.

Comment: The other tabs should not and do not call the `logout()` method. It simply changes the reactive `Meteor.userId()` attribute. Do you check the userId in the publication that delivers the data to the user and avoid sending data when the `userId()` is `null`?

Comment: Thanks @MasterAM. I found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause. It was because I try to avoid sending data on `Meteor.publish()` if users is not logged in. The problem is I do not return anything on that case.
My solution is return `this.ready()` when the user is not logged in like this:

```
Meteor.publish("myCollections", function (){
    if (!this.userId) return this.ready();

    return MyCollections.find({owner: this.userId});
});
```

Comment: This a fairly common Meteor idiom. However, while this fixes the data leak, it will not necessarily help you detect the logout itself. Using the reactive data sources I mentioned in my answer will help you track the user's login status explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! I was having this same exact issue (client getting into limbo state where it thinks it is logged in and connected after a token is expired) and going back to make sure there was a this.ready() at the end of all publications, especially those checking for this.userId solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the [meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_logoutotherclients), you can use `Meteor.logoutOtherClients()` before calling `Meteor.logout()`.

Comment: I don't think this will resolve the problem since `Meteor.logoutOtherClients()` will log the user out on other browsers (and devices) but not the current session.

Answer (score -1):

Normal (as in non-incognito) browser tabs share the same session resume token. The Meteor server will update them all when the user status changes for the associated session.

It is possible to reactively track the login status using 2 reactive calls:

- `Meteor.userId()` - return the user's id or null if no user is logged in.
- `Meteor.loggingIn()` - returns true if the user is currently in the transient state of logging in and false otherwise.

The status may take a few seconds to update across tabs, but it will happen eventually. It is up to you to detect those changes and act upon them.

You can easily test this by running the following reactive code in the consoles of 2 open tabs connected to the same Meteor server:

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
    console.info('logging in');
  } else if (Meteor.userId()) {
    console.info('logged in');
  } else {
    console.info('logged out');
  }
});
```

Try to log in and log out from one of the tab and watch the other follow along.

Using this technique, you could track the login state and change your application state and do something accordingly (e.g, redirect/render a different view or layout) when the login state changes.

Comment: I followed your instruction but still not be able to track the logged out on other tabs. Is it possible cause by `publishComposite` that I use to publish the users collection (only `_id` and `profile`)?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Also, not sure if something changed recently, but if you log out in a separate tab in the same app, the remaining tabs receive a `c[1000,"Normal closure"]` WebSocket message, then the socket closes, spawns a new one, and the user is still logged in. Meteor.user(), Accounts.user(), and Meteor.userId() all still return the original logged-in user.