# How to capture Meteor.logoutOtherClients (loss of session?) on client that gets logged out

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am trying to make sure my users don't leave too many devices/browsers connected to our web app at any given time.

I'm unable to figure out how to reasonably utilize `Meteor.logoutOtherClients` however.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function () {
    Meteor.logoutOtherClients(function(error){
       // stuff
   });
});
```

If i call `logoutOtherClients` it does indeed force that connection to be killed to the server. However, it does not update the `Meteor.userId` or logged in status for that client. It still shows the same `Meteor.userId` and roles etc. This in turn makes it difficult to throw up any kind of **You've been logged out!** kind of message... How can I detect when the session has been killed to alert the client?

Comment: I had the same issue, and found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35584024/meteor-log-out-do-not-sync-between-tabs/35587439

Make sure to `return this.ready()` at the end of all publications, especially those that have an `if(this.userId){}` in them.

Answer (score 3):

One cause is not returning `this.ready()` from publications that will not publishing anything if the user is not logged in.

```
Meteor.publish("myCollections", function (){
    if(this.userId){
       return MyCollections.find({owner: this.userId});
    }
    return this.ready(); // <--- This is the important piece to remember
});
```

Comment: I'll have to check and see if this is related to the issue I was having. I've kind of abandoned it for now as I've moved on to some other bigger issues. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Meteor.userId()` is a reactive variable on the client, try using `Tracker.autorun` to capture the state of `Meteor.userId()`.

```
import {Meteor} from "meteor/meteor";
import {Tracker} from "meteor/tracker";
import {Accounts} from "meteor/accounts-base";

Accounts.onLogin(function () {
  Tracker.autorun(function (c) {
    const userId = Meteor.userId();
    if (!userId) {
      // user has been logged out somehow.
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say. `Meteor.userId()` is not updating reactively. I simply lose connection on that client and nothing else happens. If I type `Meteor.userId()` on the client console that should have been "logged out", I simply see everything as it was. ID, Profile, roles etc. Nothing changed. It just has no connection to the server at this point. All requests are dead.  I actually have the above code already in my `Accounts.onLogin`

Comment: @btbJosh Did you ever find a solution to this? I am finding the same issue, when the resumeToken expires, or when calling logoutOtherClients, the other clients that are connected act they they are connected and logged in, but all method calls and subscriptions simply queue up and never complete. I can even disconnect and reconnect on the console and the connection is good, but the Accounts package on the client still thinks it is logged in.